# how to generate reversed array like binary number php

Tags: php

sorry if the title is a little confusing. 
i am stuck in generating an array like this.

```
array(" one_third", " two_third", " two_third", " one_third", " one_third", " two_third", " two_third",..., " one_third", " one_third");
```

so basically i want an array like `0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0` how to generate that in php or any other progaming language.

i tried

```
$ass = array();
  for($x = 0; $x <= 200; $x++){
    if($x == 0){
      array_push($ass, " one_third");
    }else if($x == 1){
      array_push($ass, " two_third");
    }else{
      if(count($ass) == 2){
        array_push($ass, " two_third");
      }else{
        if($ass[count($ass)-1] == " two_third" && $ass[count($ass)-2] == " two_third"){
          array_push($ass, " one_third");
        }else if($ass[count($ass)-1] == " one_third" && $ass[count($ass)-2] == " one_third"){
          array_push($ass, " two_third");
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the modulus operator. Something like:

```
<?php
$ass = array();

for($x = 0; $x <= 200; $x++){
  if ($x == 0) {
    array_push($ass, " one_third");
  } else {
    if ($x % 2 == 0) {
      array_push($ass, " one_third");
      array_push($ass, " one_third");
    } else {
      array_push($ass, " two_third");
      array_push($ass, " two_third");
    }
  }
}
print_r($ass);
?>
```

Comment: almost..but it is output `Array
(
    [0] =>  one_third
    [1] =>  two_third
    [2] =>  two_third
    [3] =>  one_third
    [4] =>  two_third
    [5] =>  two_third
    [6] =>  one_third
    ...
    [n] =>  two_third
)`

only one occurane of "one_third" after double "two_third"

Comment: Whoops.  Sorry about that.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into the php.net/array_map function that runs a function against each value of an array and constructs a new array. The "map" function

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)

```
$ar = array(" one_third", " two_third", " two_third", " one_third", " one_third", " two_third", " two_third", " one_third", " one_third");

$result = array_map(function($item) {
    return (int) (trim($item) === "two_third");
  },
  $ar
);

var_export($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an algorithm where you can pass array of pieces with variable size.
Function definition:

```
function getReversed($pieces, $length) {
    $output = array();

    // prevent to execute empty array
    if(empty($pieces))
        return $output;

    for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++) {
        $c = count($pieces);
        $output[] = $pieces[(floor($i/$c)%2)?abs($i%$c-$c+1):($i%$c)];
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Few examples:

```
$test = array('a', 'b');
print_r( getReversed($test, 10) );

// result:

Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => b
    [3] => a
    [4] => a
    [5] => b
    [6] => b
    [7] => a
    [8] => a
    [9] => b
)

$test = array('one', 'two', 'three');
print_r( getReversed($test, 8) );

// result
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
    [3] => three
    [4] => two
    [5] => one
    [6] => one
    [7] => two
)
```